# Как составить sql запрос для того чтобы пронумеровать по порядку записи в таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как составить sql mysql запрос для того чтобы пронумеровать по порядку записи в таблице в **заранее подготовленой колонке** ?

Желательно 1 запросом если это реально.

Comment: Согласно какому порядку вставить номера?

Comment: от 1 и далее о порядку

Comment: Это ясно, имеется в виду если строки уже имеют например ID от 1 до N то в каком порядке им присвоить другие номера? (и вообще зачем если ID это уже готовые порядковые номера)

Comment: Таблица уже имеет данные и id там не порядковый номер добавления

Comment: @Georgeeeb если вы не записывали порядковый номер добавления, то сейчас вы уже не узнаете в каком порядке были добавлены записи.

Comment: @Georgeeeb а как получилось что `id там не порядковый номер добавления`?

Comment: Какая польза от такой нумерации?

Comment: @Darth нужна была нумерация исходя их сортировки

Comment: @BuilderC это нужно для расположения положения товара в магазине в заданном порядке

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
update table set field=@num:=@num+1
 where 0 in(select @num:=0)
```

Нумерация пойдет с 1. При желании можно подправить стартовое значение и способ вычисления следующего

Answer (score 1):

Будет достаточно поставить заранее подготовленной колонке auto_increment при создании и она заполниться числами по порядку:

```
ALTER TABLE таблица ADD COLUMN (
    `заранее подготовленная колонка` int key auto_increment
);
```

или

```
ALTER TABLE таблица  CHANGE COLUMN  `заранее подготовленная колонка` `заранее подготовленная колонка` int key auto_increment;
```

Comment: Если таблица уже имеет данные?

Comment: Ничего страшного не будет. Если в таблице нет другой колонки с auto_increment, то все пойдет по плану - создастся колонка, заполненная числами (либо заполнится числами пустая колонка). А если она есть - непонятно, зачем ТС понадобилась вторая такая.. Запрос просто выдаст ошибку.