# Автоинкремент при обновлении записей mysql

Tags: mysql

Нужен запрос который сможет делать инкремент переменной при каждой итерации выборки, вот примерно как я вижу этот запрос

```
UPDATE pages SET `level` = @level++ WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Тойсть при апдейте каждой записи которая есть в `IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` нужно делать автоинкремент переменной @level.

Comment: ... set level = level + 1...

Comment: @Sergey не ))) вот что я имел введу ---- `SET @i :=0;
UPDATE  tables SET  pos = ( @i := @i +1 ) WHERE  from =  0 ORDER BY  pos`

Comment: раз вы разобрались, то или вопрос удалите, или ответ напишите

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484491/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/484506#484506