# Удаление дубликатов с изменением ID

Tags: openserver

Имеется таблица:

```
Create table Users (id_users INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, User_Name0 varchar(20) null, Name0 varchar(20) null, IP_Adress varchar(14) null);
```

Для того чтобы удалить дубликаты использую:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 GROUP BY User_Name0, Name0, IP_Adress;
```

Выходит:

```
id  \User_name0 \ Name0  \ IP_adress
499 \Belka      \Belka   \ 333
280 \Potap      \Potap   \ 222
1   \Real       \Real    \ 111
```

Как сделать:

```
id  \User_name0 \ Name0  \ IP_adress
3   \Belka      \Belka   \ 333
2   \Potap      \Potap   \ 222
1   \Real       \Real    \ 111
```

Comment: какая у вас СУБД ?  А вообще вы таблицу tmp  создавайте не запросом выборки, а отдельно создайте, поле id сделайте автоинкрементом, как в основной и потом вставляйте в нее все поля, кроме id т.е. `insert into tmp(user_name, name,ip) select user_name,name,ip ...` он им новые id сам и назначит подряд. Или используйте в запросе переменные для нумерации, примерно как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484491/

Comment: СУБД MySQL 5.7.