# Как исправить промежутки от удаленных строк MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица `cars_catalog`, в которой изначально было 250 записей. После некоторых удалений строк из таблицы, осталось 187 записей, порядок `id` был нарушен, т.е. раньше порядок `id` был `1..250`, а сейчас `1..15,17,66..112.. и т.д.`. Как сделать так чтобы значения поля `id` были `1..187`?
запрос `id`: `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: ID автоинкриментное ключ поле?  если да то так и должно быть. Это правильно. Это уникальный ID записи. Предполагается что по нему будут связи 1 ко многим. Менять такое уже нельзя. Если Вам нужен порядковый номер то такое делают запросами. При запросе идет своя нумерация. Почитайте немного про базы данных и PRIMARY ключи

Comment: а зачем вам это?

Comment: @Manul74 а можно как то иначе создать `id` чтобы он менялся следующий удаленный?

Comment: Поясните зачем Вам такое? такое над ключами в базах делать не рекоменжуется. Либо выделяется отдельное поле либо генерируется отдельным полем при выборке. Это ключ! Делать с ним ничего не нужно и часто опастно в случае если есть связи с другими таблицами

Comment: id - он не для людей, он для машины. Оставьте компьютеру компьютерово, а сами занимайтесь творчеством, а не выравниванием циферок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на таблицу не ссылаются другие, или в констрейнте стоит `ON UPDATE` `CASCADE` то можно обновить ключи и сбросить автоинкремент таблицы, если он есть:

```
SET @num = 0;
UPDATE table1 
SET id = @num := @num +1 
WHERE id > 0
ORDER BY id;

ALTER TABLE table1 auto_increment = 1;
```

Comment: Только так делать ОЧЕНЬ не рекомендуется.  Потому как пойдет потеря один ко многим если они есть.

Comment: Если FK на `ON UPDATE` делает `CASCADE` то всё должно обновиться. Хотя я согласен, что в этом случае на настоящей базе такое лучше не делать. Если база домашняя или только вводится в эксплуатацию, почему нет?)

Comment: лучше людей сразу отучать такое делать. Дома да можно попробовать. Но в рабочих системах такое делать категорически нельзя.

Comment: @manul74 это база на "первой стадии", нужно удалить записи пока их не станет 100 и не имеют значения потери поскольку значения не имеет (пока что) содержание таблицы

Comment: @Manul74 естественно делать такое на рабочей базе не нужно

Comment: @MidNightElf  еще раз повторюсь. Приучитесь этого не делать уже сейчас. даже просто попробовать.

Comment: 1) Укажите явно, что переменной @num следует присвоить нулевое значение перед выполнением запроса - иначе неминуема ошибка с сообщением "Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1". 2) Для верного лучше выполнять `ALTER TABLE table1 auto_increment = 1;` - вместо единицы будет пересчитано и установлено правильное значение автоинкремента. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7913996544ac219f332b48dd5a028074)

Comment: @RusArtM Кстати, отдельный set перед запросом все таки не обязателен, инициализировать переменную можно и прямо в запросе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484506/194569

Comment: @Mike Ещё можно с помощью `IFNULL(@num, 0)`, мне так больше нравится. Но это уже детали :)

Comment: @RusArtM А вот нельзя :) Что если перед этим запросом выполнялся другой и оставил после себя какое то значение в `@num`

Comment: @Mike Да, в случае повторных выполнений так не пойдёт. Но в данном случае приемлемо, т.к. выполнить процедуру нужно один раз. Но вообще соглашусь, что лучше сделать это по другому.